# raise H2OValueError (message=message, var_name=vname, skip_frames=1)

Tags: python, h2o, names, valueerror

I'm trying to set column names, but I encounter an error:

> H2OValueError: Argument `names`

Code:

```
index_columns_names =  ["Date"]
generator_output_columns_names = ["GenOut"]
generator_v_columns_names = ["GenVar"]
turb_bearing_vib_columns_names =["TurbBearingVib"+str(i) for i in range(1,6)]
gen_bearing_vib_columns_names = ["GenBearingVib"+str(i) for i in range(7,9)]
input_file_column_names = index_columns_names + generator_output_columns_names + generator_v_columns_names + turb_bearing_vib_columns_names + gen_bearing_vib_columns_names
data = h2o.upload_file("data\Data_SLA_Unit_1_2018.csv")
data.set_names(input_file_column_names);
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your naming convention, are you expecting input_file_column_names to be a list of 12 strings? When printing we see the following 10 column names:

```
['Date',
 'GenOut',
 'GenVar',
 'TurbBearingVib1',
 'TurbBearingVib2',
 'TurbBearingVib3',
 'TurbBearingVib4',
 'TurbBearingVib5',
 'GenBearingVib7',
 'GenBearingVib8']
```

In H2O-3 version 3.22.1.3, `data.set_names(input_file_column_names)` worked successfully for any dataset that had 10 columns but gave the following error if the number of columns was more or less than the number of strings:

*H2OValueError: Argument `names` (= ['Date', 'GenOut', 'GenVar']) does not satisfy the condition len(names) == self.ncol*